Best way to offset the target reference of another cell?
Suppose I have a value in cell $SheetX.A1 (say then number 42).
Now, I reference this value in another cell, say $SheetY.M5 by setting its content to =$SheetX.A1 (so I see "42" in cell M5 of sheet Y).
How can I offset the reference targeted by M5 in another cell? For example I would like M6 to target the same location M5 is referencing, offset by 6 rows, in other words I would like M6 to show the value of $SheetX.A7 (six rows down from $SheetX.A1) because that is what M5 is referencing. Something like "=OFFSET(TARGET(M5),6)".

I know that if I can get a value with =INDIRECT("addr")
I also know that I can get the formula of a cell with =FORMULA(ref), so =FORMULA(M5) will return $SheetX.A1

I suppose I could do some string manipulation on that to remove the equals sign and then amend the trailing number 1 to increment it, somehow generating text "$Sheet.A7" which I can pass to INDIRECT()?
How does one go about doing this? What is the best way?

You can try this formula:
=LET(start,M5,offsetRows,5,
target,INDIRECT(MID(FORMULATEXT(start),2,LEN(FORMULATEXT(start))-1)),
IF(ISERROR(target),"n.a.",OFFSET(target,offsetRows,0)
))

It will offset if the INDIRECTof the formula returns a valid result - otherwise it will return n.a. (e.g. if formula in D1 =$SheetX.A1+1)

You can use this formula:
=INDIRECT("'" & MID(FORMULATEXT(M1), 2, FIND("!", FORMULATEXT(M1)) - 2) & "'!" & ADDRESS(ROW(M1) + 6, COLUMN(A1)))

It first extracts the sheet and then constructs the reference to the cell 6 rows below the current row.

Thank you. I went with Ike's answer because storing the values in semantic variables helps readability and is more flexible, but upvoting this as a correct succinct answer.

If you have Microsoft 365, you could define a named formula for ease of use:

Use of INDIRECT is usually frowned upon, but using it here with that awareness :)
Define a named formula indirectOFFSET
ref could be single cell or an array
For example=indirectOFFSET(M5,6) or =indirectOFFSET(M5:M10,6,1)

=LAMBDA(ref, [rows_], [cols_],
    LET(
        rows_, IF(ISOMITTED(rows_), 0, rows_),
        cols_, IF(ISOMITTED(cols_), 0, cols_),
        offset_one, LAMBDA(ref,
            LET(
                ref_addr, IF(
                    ISREF(ref),
                    LET(f, FORMULATEXT(ref), RIGHT(f, LEN(f) - 1)),
                    NA()
                ),
                OFFSET(INDIRECT(ref_addr), rows_, cols_)
            )
        ),
        MAP(ref, offset_one)
    )
)

Without formatting, as entered in Name Manager:
=LAMBDA(ref,[rows_],[cols_], LET(rows_, IF(ISOMITTED(rows_), 0, rows_), cols_, IF(ISOMITTED(cols_), 0, cols_), offset_one, LAMBDA(ref, LET(ref_addr, IF(ISREF(ref), LET(f, FORMULATEXT(ref), RIGHT(f, LEN(f) - 1)), NA()), OFFSET(INDIRECT(ref_addr), rows_, cols_))), MAP(ref, offset_one)))



I assume INDEX() with SEQUENCE() should work. Try-
=INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A100,SEQUENCE(5,1,1,6))



I think you've misunderstood the question. You entered the location Shee1!A1... directly in the formula of cell E5. What I am after is this: suppose you set D5 to equal =$Sheet1!A1. Can you set E5 to reference a relative location to "whatever D5 is referencing + an offset of 6"? So currently D5 is referencing A1 therefore E5 would show A7. If I edit D5 to reference A3 then E5 should immediately start showing A10 (which is A3 + 7 rows). Hope I've clarified it.
